# Why is my app not showing up for 1.5 users in the Android Market?

Tags: android, google-play, android-1.5-cupcake

The app is [Flash Cards Max](http://www.FlashCardsMax.com) on the Android market. I recently updated my app with a 1.6 only feature. However, I still want the app to work with those that have Android 1.5.  I built it using Android 1.6 in Eclipse and I have the correct strings in the Android manifest file.

```
<uses-sdk 
    android:minSdkVersion="3"
    android:targetSdkVersion="4"
 />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET"></uses-permission>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.RECEIVE_BOOT_COMPLETED" />
```

Everything works in the emulator fine on 1.5 just want to be sure it shows up on the Android Market for those with 1.5. It does not.  This is a market filtering question.

Please see [this thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4058954/using-eclipse-how-can-i-build-compile-an-android-project-targeted-for-1-5-that) for info on what I changed and how I went about it thanks to several of your suggestions.

tl;dr

Why doesn't my app show up for 1.5 users?

Comment: Why don't you set up your emulator to view the market?

Comment: Didn't know you could do that. I did so and am not seeing it. I've revised my question.

Comment: I've also tried it now with just android:minSdkVersion="3" without any luck.

Answer (score 0):

Answer by a helpful user on Reddit.

"I had the same problem, solution was `<supports-screens/>`

Why?

Because

```
android:anyDensity

Indicates whether the application can accommodate any screen density. Older applications (pre API Level 4) are assumed unable to accomodate all densities and this is "false" by default. Applications using API Level 4 or higher are assumed able to and this is "true" by default. You can explicitly supply your abilities here."
```